# Validate parameters, set by $this->request->setArgument()

Tags: validation, typo3, fluid, extbase

I have a controller action, which accepts 3 parameters: 1st is built from Fluid form, 2 others are created in `initialize*()` action and provided to request.

```
protected function initializeCombinedAction()
{
    // creation of ObjectStorage's $firstList and $secondList
    $this->request->setArgument('firstList', $firstList);
    $this->request->setArgument('secondList', $secondList);
}

/**
 *
 * @param \Vendor\Ext\Domain\Model\MyModel $mymodel
 * @param \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<\Vendor\Ext\Domain\Model\SubModel>    $firstList
 * @param \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<\Vendor\Ext\Domain\Model\SubModel>    $secondList
 */
public function combinedAction(Model\MyModel $mymodel, $firstList, $secondList)
{
// some code here
}
```

`$firstList` and `$secondList` created as arrays as if they were provided in request. `PropertyMapper` recognizes them and maps correctly, resulting in two `ObjectStorage`'s holding instances of `SubModel` are available as action arguments.

But the problem is, that no validation of `SubModel` is made.
With 1st argument validators are executed, but not for 2nd and 3rd.

Shoould I somehow explicitly define such validation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to **Dimitri L.**, I was pointed into right direction.

The answer is: Extbase validates all the action parameters, no matter how they are constructed, but it doesn't automatically resolve validators for parameters of `ObjectStorage` type.

Luckily there is already built-in `CollectionValidator`, which can be used exactly for this purpose.

So, my initial action signature will look like this:

```
/**
 * @param \Vendor\Ext\Domain\Model\MyModel $mymodel
 * @param \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<\Vendor\Ext\Domain\Model\SubModel>    $firstList
 * @param \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<\Vendor\Ext\Domain\Model\SubModel>    $secondList
 * @validate $firstList Collection(elementType=\Vendor\Ext\Domain\Model\SubModel)
 * @validate $secondList Collection(elementType=\Vendor\Ext\Domain\Model\SubModel)
 */
public function combinedAction(Model\MyModel $mymodel, $firstList, $secondList)
{
// some code here
}
```

Additionally I've created an issue on TYPO3 Forge: [#78546](https://forge.typo3.org/issues/78546).

Answer (score 1):

The problem should be that there are no default validators for the ObjectStorage. You can always set the validation yourself like that:

```
 * @validate $firstList \Vendor\Ext\Domain\Validator\ListValidator
```

Comment: Thank you for this point. I thought, that ObjectStorage items should be validated due to recursive validation in Extbase, because `MyModel` object contains list of `SubModel`s, linked via ObjectStorage as well and in this case they are validated. I've tried to add 4th parameter of type `MyModel` same way, as I add 2nd and 3rd and it's validator as well as validators of it's properties were executed. So, the problem is really in validation of arguments of `ObjectStorage` type.